# .htaccess redirect all pages to same page on new server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am moving hosts and i have been advised to set up a redirect whilst the DNS changes are being progressed. The site structure on my new server is identical to my current server so all i need is the base url changed. E.g.

http://www.mysite.com/Category1

Will redirect to:

http://[my new ip address]/Category1

Help is really appreciated

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://1.2.3.4/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks @duncan. This works however for some reason my new server isnt resolving to index.php when the redirect kicks in. So it works for every page except http://www.mysite.com. How can i make http://www.mysite.com redirect to http://[my new ip address]/index.php

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can stick to mod_alias:

```
Redirect / http://{new ip address}/
```

Comment: This is just the simplest and most elegant way if you want everything to just work after changing hostname. Works perfectly for me.

Comment: You can also optionally pass an HTTP status code as second argument, like: `Redirect 301 / http://{new ip address}/`